# Is there a way to legally cast a Mockito mock object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, polymorphism, discord-jda

I wrote a couple of test case classes for my small Discord bot in Java 11, JUnit Jupiter 5.6.0, Mockito 3.3.3, and Java Discord API 4.1.1_122.

I realized that my test cases had multiple instances of repeated behavior, including the declaration of equal mocks used for the same purpose, and the repetition of `given([method call]).willReturn([object]);` in my `@BeforeEach` startup method. I wished to separate the repeated behavior into base classes to organize myself, but I am stuck.
All of my test classes test some kind of event handler in the Java Discord API framework, so I made a top level class named `GenericEventTest`:

```java
public abstract class GenericEventTest {
    @Mock
    protected GenericEvent eventMock;

    @Mock
    protected JDA jdaMock;

    protected GenericEventTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        given(   eventMock.getJDA()   )
                .willReturn(jdaMock);
    }
}
```

I wished to implement a high-level mock for the event to polymorphically fit into my test classes, then put the designated `given()` command in the class that it belongs, because all of my tests repeat this same line.
Next, I realized that all of my tests were testing some kind of event related to messages in Discord. So I extended `GenericEvent` and made `GuildMessageEventTest`:

```java
public abstract class GuildMessageEventTest extends GenericEventTest {
    @Mock
    protected GenericGuildMessageEvent eventMock;

    @Mock
    protected TextChannel eventChannelMock;

    @Mock
    protected MessageAction messageActionMock;

    protected GuildMessageEventTest() {
        super();

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        given(   eventMock.getChannel()   )
                .willReturn(eventChannelMock);

        given(   eventChannelMock.sendMessage(anyString())   )
                .willReturn(messageActionMock);
    }
}
```

My idea is to implement the next level of event in this class, `GenericGuildMessageEvent` which will have the same `given()` rules applied to it from `GenericEvent`, and then add the appropriate `given()` rules in this class. But I believe I have found my problem.

When I declare `@Mock protected GenericGuildMessageEvent eventMock;` I am **shadowing** the `GenericEvent eventMock` from `GenericEventTest`. So, I am declaring the `GenericGuildMessageEvent` instance, but I am not **retaining** the `given()` rules that were attached to the mock in `GenericEventTest`. Doing something like `@Mock protected GenericGuildMessageEvent eventMock = (GenericGuildMessageEvent) super.eventMock;` will not work, because objects annotated with `@Mock` cannot be legally casted in this way.

My question is this: how can I legally up-cast my instance of `GenericEvent` into a `GenericGuildMessageEvent` while having Mockito copy the `given()` rules attached to the `GenericEvent` instance in the superclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `abstract GenericEvent getEventMock();` method in your `GenericEventTest` and have `GuildMessageEventTest` implement it. Then move instance field `protected GenericEvent eventMock`from your base class to sub class. Use `getEventMock()`to access your mock in base class. Note that `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is not required again in your sub class. This will overwrite mocked behavior from your base class.

```
// GenericEventTest
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

public abstract class GenericEventTest {

    protected GenericEventTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        given(getEventMock().getJDA()).willReturn("jdaMock");
    }

    abstract GenericEvent getEventMock();
}

// GuildMessageEventTest
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

public abstract class GuildMessageEventTest extends GenericEventTest {
    @Mock
    protected GenericGuildMessageEvent eventMock;

    @Mock
    protected GenericGuildMessageEvent myMock;

    @Override
    public GenericGuildMessageEvent getEventMock() {
        return eventMock;
    }

    protected GuildMessageEventTest() {
        super();

//        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        given(eventMock.getChannel())
                .willReturn("eventChannelMock");

    }
}

//The Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

public class ActualMessageTest extends GuildMessageEventTest {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void testX() {
        assertEquals("eventChannelMock", eventMock.getChannel());
        assertEquals("jdaMock", eventMock.getJDA());
        assertNotNull(myMock);
    }

}
```